# Labeling axes using extra x ticks and extra y ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to write code so that `TikZ` will compile it to label the axes with `x` and `y` using `extra x ticks=` and `extra y ticks=` in the same way 
that `TikZ` will label the axes using `xlabel=$x$`, `ylabel=$y$`, `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}`,
and `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}`.  (The reason for this is that I may use `xlabel` and `ylabel` to put titles along the axes.)  Right now, I have

`extra x ticks={}` and `extra y ticks={}`

because `TikZ` does not compile the code with

`extra x ticks={$x$}` and `extra y ticks={$y$}`

What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-42.5,xmax=42.5,
    ymin=-42.5,ymax=42.5,
    restrict y to domain=-42.5:42.5,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    extra x ticks={},extra y ticks={},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}},
    extra y tick style={yticklabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-40:64/41,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=32/13:40,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)} node[above,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\frac{x+16}{x-2}$};

\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] {1} node[above,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] (2,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=2$};

\addplot coordinates{(5,7)} node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$(5,7)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use the extra ticks for the titles along the axes?

Comment: @Alenanno   I guess that using the extra ticks for the titles along the axes is a better choice.  The code that I have "should" work.  Why do I get errors with `extra x ticks={$x$}`?

Comment: Because that is not defining a label, it's defining a tick mark. So it requires a number.

Comment: @Alenanno  To label the axes in my other codes, I have used `xlabel=$x$,` `ylabel=$y$,` `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},` and `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}`.  What is the analog using `extra x ticks`?

Comment: First of all, `xlabel` and `ylabel` require braces. Instead of `at={(ticklabel* cs:`, I'd use `at={(axis description cs:`, it's easier to use I think. Anyway, see answer below, you can modify it to use it as you wish.

Comment: @Alenanno  I think that I will use `at={(axis description cs:` to position the labels for the axes.  It is consistent with other commands that I use.

Comment: @Alenanno  Using a node command, how would I position the labels `x` and `y` in the same locations as obtained using `at={(axis description cs:`?

Comment: Well, of course: `\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:1,.5) {$x$};` for the x axis. Do the same for the other, changing the coordinates.

Comment: @Alenanno  I just compiled the code with both `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},` and `\node[anchor=north west] at (axis description cs:1,.5) {$x$};`.  There is only one `x` typeset.  How is `(ticklabel* cs:1)}` and `anchor=north west` the same as `axis description cs:1, 0.5`?

Comment: Maybe they overlap each other although I don't know how ticklabel cs works, do you might need to check the manual.

Comment: @Alenanno  Yes, both commands typeset the `x`. (The `x` appears slightly darker than the `y`.)  I looked at the manual about the position of typesetting `x` using `(ticklabel* cs:1)` awhile ago.  I remember it not being helpful.  I will look again.  You may see a post about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I would do the opposite. Use the axis labels for the axes and then use the extra ticks for any extra information.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-42.5,xmax=42.5,
    ymin=-42.5,ymax=42.5,
    restrict y to domain=-42.5:42.5,
    xtick={},ytick={},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},  
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,.5)},anchor=north west},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:.5,1)},anchor=south west},
    extra x ticks={5},
    extra x tick label={Hello!},
    every extra x tick/.style={tick label style={fill=none, rotate=-45,anchor=west}},
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-40:64/41,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=32/13:40,blue] {(x + 16)/(x - 2)} node[above,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y=\frac{x+16}{x-2}$};

\addplot[dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] {1} node[above,pos=0.1,font=\footnotesize]{$y=1$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex, samples=2, domain=-42.5:42.5] (2,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=2$};

\addplot coordinates{(5,7)} node[anchor=west,font=\footnotesize]{$(5,7)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```